# java no such method (java.lang.NoSuchMethodException) exception

Tags: java

I am calling my method dynamically like this:

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method;
method = TestRecommendations.class.getMethod("level1classSimilarityForUser",
                                String[].class);
```

If you go to the class `TestRecommendations`, you will see that I do have it :

```
public ResultSet level1ClassSimilarityForUser(String ... userURI) {
```

what is my mistake please?

Comment: `level1ClassSimilarityForUser`, not `level1classSimilarityForUser`. It's case sensitive.

Comment: @AndyTurner now I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch` could you help please ?

Comment: Could you correct your question and typo, and then share us the error messages?

Comment: @tsuda7 i asked a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447647/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-argument-type-mismatch-on-string-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo in `level1classSimilarityForUser`, try `level1ClassSimilarityForUser`.

Comment: now I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`