# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch on string array

Tags: java

This is my code to invoke a method dynamically:

```
String[] parameters = new String[requiredParameters.length];
//here i put some values in the parameters array
method = TestRecommendations.class.getMethod("level1ClassSimilarityForUser",
                                    String[].class);
System.out.println(":" + parameters[0] + ":");
results = (ResultSet) method.invoke(new TestRecommendations(), parameters)
```

`parameters` is a string array, and this is the declaration of my `level1ClassSimilarityForUser` method

```
public ResultSet level1ClassSimilarityForUser(String[] userURI) {
```

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`invoke` expects an `Object[]` as second argument (varargs is just a convenience syntax).
I think in your case the `String[]` is not taken as the first vararg argument, but the complete vararg `Object[]` and thus your single strings are used as arguments which does not match `String[]`.
In your case, explicitly wrapping your parameters in an `Object` array before giving it to `invoke` should work.
So do `results = (ResultSet) method.invoke(new TestRecommendations(), new Ojbect[] { parameters })` instead